# unable to click the located css path for my element

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to automate my test cases for my application.I have added code and a screen shot as well for your reference.
There is only one add button in the application so its easy for me to write an event for add.But as shown in screen there is lots of delete button existing. so it was tough for me to automate for dynamic delete button.as of now i am trying to write code for deleting all the records.But neither of Id nor class is working in html code which as written.Please help.

screen shot is in https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrohh.jpg
btn inverse and icon trash are to class identifiers i found

```js
package framework;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class exceloperation {
    WebDriver driver;
 public Object perform;
    public exceloperation(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void perform(Properties p,String operation,String objectName,String objectType,String value) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("");
        switch (operation.toUpperCase()) {
      /*  case"OPENBROWSER":
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().window().maximize();*/
        case "CLICK":
            //Perform click
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(objectName,objectType)).click();
            break;
        case "SETTEXT":
            //Set text on control
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(objectName,objectType)).sendKeys(value);
            break;
             
        case "GOTOURL":
            //Get url of application
            driver.get(value);
            break;
        case "GETTEXT":
            //Get text of an element
            driver.findElement(this.getObject(objectName,objectType)).getText();
            break;
        case "DELETEALL":
         
         /*    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("phContent_gvEstimate"));
       List<WebElement> allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
             for(WebElement row : allRows)
        {
          List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
          boolean required_row = true;
        for (WebElement cell : cells) 
          {
            if(required_row)
            {
          List<WebElement> mylinks = cell.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
          System.out.println("num of mylinks : "+mylinks.size());
         for(WebElement mylink : mylinks )
            {
               String linkid= mylink.getAttribute("id");
               Thread.sleep(5000);
                if(linkid.contains("Delete"))
                   {
                    System.out.println(" Pressing : " + linkid + " By Clicking " + driver.findElement(By.id(linkid)));
                driver.findElement(By.id(linkid)).click();
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
                   alert.accept(); 
                   Thread.sleep(5000);
                   driver.navigate().refresh();
                   allRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
                   
            }
               else {

                System.out.println("Cannot be deleted");

               }
            }
         }
        }
       }*/
        List<WebElement> del_elements=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        for(WebElement mylink :del_elements)
        {
            String linkid= mylink.getAttribute("id");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
         System.out.println("Deleting element:" + linkid);
        }
         default:
            break;
        }
    }
     
    /**
     * Find element BY using object type and value
     * @param p
     * @param objectName
     * @param objectType
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private By getObject(String objectName,String objectType) throws Exception{
        //Find by xpath
        if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("XPATH")){
             
            return By.xpath(objectName);
        }
        //find by class
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("CLASSNAME")){
             
            return By.className(objectName);
             
        }
        //find by name
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("ID")){
             
            return By.id(objectName);
             
        }
        //Find by css
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("CSS")){
             
            return By.cssSelector(objectName);
             
        }
        //find by link
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("LINK")){
             
            return By.linkText(objectName);
             
        }
        //find by partial link
        else if(objectType.equalsIgnoreCase("PARTIALLINK")){
             
            return By.partialLinkText(objectName);
             
        }else
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong object type");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="widget-box">
<div class="widget-title">
<div class="widget-content nopadding">
<div id="ProgramTableContainer" style="overflow: auto;">
<div class="table-main-container">
<div class="table-busy-panel-background" style="display: none;"></div>
<div class="table-busy-message" style="display: none;"></div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover data-table">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="table-data-row table-row-even" data-record-key="48">
<td class="child-opener-image-column">
<img class="child-opener-image" title="Projects" src="../../Content/images/Misc/Plus.png">
</td>
<td>
<td>
<span>2015</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>01/26/2015</span>
</td>
<td>
<span>02/17/2015</span>
</td>
<td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-primary">
</td>
<td>
<a class="btn btn-inverse">
<i class="icon-trash"></i>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-data-row" data-record-key="49">
<tr class="table-data-row table-row-even" data-record-key="44">
<tr class="table-data-row" data-record-key="45">
<tr class="table-data-row table-row-even" data-record-key="42">
<tr class="table-data-row" data-record-key="46">
<tr class="table-data-row table-row-even" data-record-key="47">
<tr class="table-data-row" data-record-key="43">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to click the `<a>` element in this table cell:

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-inverse">
        <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </a>
</td>
```

What is unique about this element? If you know that any button with the `btn-inverse` class will always be a delete button, look for that. This xPath locator is looking for any `<a>` elements whose class attribute value contains `btn-inverse`.

```
List<WebElement> del_elements=driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[contains(@class,'btn-inverse')]"));
```

If this does not work, you'll most likely want to take into account the `<i class="icon-trash">` child. This xPath locator will search for the `<a>` element that has a child `<i>` element with a class attribute value of `icon-trash`

```
List<WebElement> del_elements=driver.findElements(By.xPath("//a[i/@class='icon-trash']"));
```

Also note that none of these elements have an `id` attribute, so your `linkid` string in your code below will always be empty:

```
for(WebElement mylink :del_elements)
{
    mylink.Click();
    // do anything else here to handle deleting the entry

    String linkid= mylink.getAttribute("id");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
     System.out.println("Deleting element:" + linkid);
 }
```

Comment: the line where the list<WebElement> del_elements=driver.findElements(By.xPath("//i[@class='icon-trash']/preceding-sibling::a")); is throughing exception....

Comment: Ah, I misread the html. the <i> element is a child, not a sibling of the <a> element we want to click on. I've updated my answer - try using the "//a[i/@class='icon-trash']" xPath locator string.

Comment: thanks alot for your help....i have been trying from10days to write the path..great job by stackoverflow....but now i am facing issue with my alert dialog box....i have given "alert.accept" in my code...but its not working.any help is appreciable.

Comment: public void checkAlert() {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //exception handling
    }
}

Comment: this code i got from stackoverflow...this worked for me for alert.accept.....thanks once again...